# Change of variable in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the equation $a(x)y'' + b(x)y'+c(x)y=0$, if $\zeta=1/x$, we can change the variables in $y''$ and $y'$. However, I'm not so sure what to do with $y(x)$ itself? How does it get changed to become $y(\zeta)$, if it's changed at all, since $y(\zeta)$ and $y(\frac{1}{\zeta})$ are both functions of $\zeta$?

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=\frac{d}{dx}y$$
$$y'=\frac{d}{d \xi}y \frac{d \xi}{dx}$$
$$y'= -\xi ^2\frac{d}{d \xi}y$$
$$y''=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y= \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{d}{dx}y)$$
$$y''= \frac{d}{d \xi}(-\xi ^2\frac{d}{d \xi}y)\frac{d \xi}{dx}$$
$$= (-2\xi\frac{d}{d \xi}y-\xi ^2\frac{d^2}{d \xi^2}y)(-\xi^2)$$
So,
$$a(x)y''(x)+b(x)y'(x)+c(x)y(x)=0$$
$$\rightarrow a(\frac{1}{\xi})(2\xi^3\frac{d}{d \xi}y+\xi ^4\frac{d^2}{d \xi^2}y(\frac{1}{\xi})-b(\frac{1}{\xi})\xi ^2\frac{d}{d \xi}y(\frac{1}{\xi})+c(\frac{1}{\xi})y(\frac{1}{\xi})=0$$
$$=a(\frac{1}{\xi})\xi ^4\frac{d^2}{d \xi^2}y(\frac{1}{\xi})+(a(\frac{1}{\xi})2\xi^3-b(\frac{1}{\xi})\xi ^2)\frac{d}{d \xi}y(\frac{1}{\xi})+c(\frac{1}{\xi})y(\frac{1}{\xi})=0$$

Comment: Can we instead write $y(\zeta)$, $c(\zeta)$, etc?

Comment: It's honestly going to depend on what your functions were. Sometimes a transformation is helpful and sometimes it is more work than necessary. If you want to write $y(\xi)$ instead of $y(\frac{1}{\xi})$ then you are just reversing back to the original ODE. At least, that is what it sounds like, more context or a specific problem would be helpful.